# ruby2/rails4: How do I set a variable in a model that can then be available to multiple methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model for Event.  This is a super simple model that has two before_save callbacks.

One of them is:

```
def set_note
   if status == "ON"
     core = RubySpark::Tinker.new(ENV["COREID"])
     core.digital_write(0, "HIGH")
   elsif status == "OFF"
     core = RubySpark::Tinker.new(ENV["COREID"])
     core.digital_write(0, "LOW")
   end 
end
```

I previously had the 'core = RubySpark' outside of the method but the app returned an error that 'core' was an invalid local variable.  Can I set it as a instance Variable?  IS it ok to set an instance variable in a model?

Comment: Of course. Instance variables are an intrinsic part of all Ruby classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference for this would be to extract some of the code into another method.

Something like this:

```
def set_note
  if status == "ON"
    core_digital(0, "HIGH")
  elsif status == "OFF"
    core_digital(0, "LOW")
  end 
end

def core_digital(num, val)
  core_method.digital_write(num, val)
end

def core_method
  RubySpark::Tinker.new(ENV["COREID"])
end
```

You would probably want to name the method something more meaningful than my example.

Comment: Would also incorporate the memoization as suggested by @vee to this

Comment: Ok this makes sense, and I like factoring  it out, but I will be using 'core' in a whole other method as well.  And in that instance its not using the digital_write method.  it uses a different method.  At this point I am using 'core' 3 times.

Comment: I edited the code and extracted the rubyspark call into it's own method. This way you can call 'core' as many times as you want. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how many times this method gets called, or really, how many times `RubySpark::Tinker.new(ENV["COREID"]` gets called.  If it's only one time then declaring it as an instance variable is not necessary.  You could do:

```
def set_note
   core = RubySpark::Tinker.new(ENV["COREID"])
   if status == "ON"
     core.digital_write(0, "HIGH")
   elsif status == "OFF"
     core.digital_write(0, "LOW")
   end 
end
```

If however, you think that this method gets executed multiple times in the same request then you could make use of `memoization` changing `core` to an instance variable and using the `||=` operator.

```
def set_note
   @core ||= RubySpark::Tinker.new(ENV["COREID"])
   if status == "ON"
     @core.digital_write(0, "HIGH")
   elsif status == "OFF"
     @core.digital_write(0, "LOW")
   end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using instance variables is the designed way for an object to keep information that should be available for multiple methods to be able to access.

Only that instance of the object will have that value (as implied by the name instance variable) so it won't negatively affect other instances.

As has already been suggested there are ways that you could use less repetition by abstracting part of your method into another method. This is a good idea, but the basic answer to your question is just "Yes, that's what it's for."